# How to revert to installed python, mac sierra 10.12.6

Tags: python, macos

Before I understood virtualenv, etc., I installed various python packages (and versions) on my mac, via easy_install, install, homebrew, and heaven knows what else.

I'd like to get rid of everything and go back to the base installation (python 2.7 or so?) as installed with mac sierra 10.12.6. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance.